# Accept mark moves a little bit in different states

Tags: bug, design

I just noticed that the checkmark is in a slightly different spot in its two states:

[image]

It's a little bit to the left when checked, and a little bit to the right when not. Could we have it stay in the same place?

Comment: What took you so long? ;)

Comment: @jonsca Blame AP testing, I hadn't got a chance to go over the new design with my brand new electron microscope yet :)

Comment: You people and your eagle eyes!

Comment: Good catch. We'll fix it.